# Efficient structure to store large number of matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, neural-network

I am now manually building a 1-layer neural network in Python without using packages like tensorflow. For this neural nets, each input is a 500 dimensional one-hot encoder, and output is a 3 dimensional vector representing probability of each class.

The neural nets works, but my problem is that the number of training instances is very large, slightly more than 1 million. And because I need to run at least 3 epochs, I cannot find an efficient way to store the weights matrix.

I tried to use a 3 dimensional numpy random matrix and dictionaries to represent weights and then perform weight update. The first dimension of 3-d matrix is number of training instances, and the later 2 are corresponding dimension that match dimension of each input and hidden layer. Both method works fine with small samples, but the program died with full sample.

```
#first feature.shape[0] is number of training samples, and feature.shape[1] is 500.
#d is the dimension of hidden layer
#using 3-d matrices
w_1 = np.random.rand(feature.shape[0], d,feature.shape[1])
b_1 = np.random.rand(feature.shape[0], 1,d)

w_2 = np.random.rand(feature.shape[0], 3, d)
b_2 = np.random.rand(feature.shape[0], 1, 3)

#iterate through every training epoch
for iteration in range(epoch):
    correct, i = 0,0
    #iterate through every training instance
    while i < feature.shape[0]:
        #net and out for hidden layer
        net1 = feature[i].toarray().flatten().dot(w_1[i].T) + b_1[i].flatten()
        h_1 = sigmoid(net1)
        #net and out for output
        y_hat = h_1.dot(w_2[i].T) + b_2[i].flatten()
        prob = softmax(y_hat)
        loss = squared_loss(label[i],prob)

        #backpropagation steps omitted here

#using dictionaries
w_1 = {i: np.random.rand(d, feature.shape[1]) for i in range(feature.shape[0])}
b_1 = {i: np.random.rand(d) for i in range(feature.shape[0])}
w_2 = {i: np.random.rand(3, d) for i in range(feature.shape[0])}
b_2 = {i: np.random.rand(3) for i in range(feature.shape[0])}

for iteration in range(epoch):
    correct, i = 0,0
    while i < feature.shape[0]:
        #net and out for hidden layer
        net1 = feature[i].toarray().flatten().dot(w_1[i].T) + b_1[i]
        h_1 = sigmoid(net1)
        #output and probabilities
        y_hat = h_1.dot(w_2[i].T) + b_2[i]
        prob = softmax(y_hat)

        loss = squared_loss(label[i],prob)
```

As you can see, I need to initialize all weights first so that when I neural nets go through each epoch, weights can be updated and will not be lost. But the problem is that this is inefficient! And program dies!

So could anyone suggest anything about this? How could I store weights and update weights in each training epoch?

Any help is greatly appreciated!